# "Information Not Found" page in Visual Studio 2008, VB.NET Express Edition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, documentation

I'm experimenting with VS 2008 Express edition and when I hit f1 on a keyword or class name I seem to get the Information Not Found page more than 90% of the time.

Is this a configuration problem? Is it because this is the "free-as-in-beer" Express edition? Did Microsoft move their online documentation since the version I downloaded?

I'm kind of amazed that here's a demo of their flagship development product which seems to be missing almost any kind of integrated reference documentation. How is the integrated help in Visual Studio meant to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the *full* MSDN Library for Visual Studio is massive - at the current time it is 2GB - so for this reason it's offered as a separate download.

There appears to be an *abriged* version which is 300MB, although I would suggest that you'd see the "Information Not Available" message every now and then with that version installed.

You can get them both for free from [MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/msdn/Default.aspx).

Personally, I have the full version installed, but if you don't want to download MSDN you can turn online help on by doing the following:

> In your Visual Studio product, select
>   Tools -> Options from the application
>   menu. Then select Environment -> Help
>   -> Online in the Options dialog. Under "When loading Help content" select
>   "Try online first, then local" and
>   click OK

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the MSDN Libary with the express edition? You need to :)

And you can also download the full version of the MSDN Documentation if you just want EVERYTHING.

The documentation is absolutely free.

What version do you have of express, then I can redirect you to a link to the full documentation, but for the express one (smaller, but proberbly have what you need), you need to run the installer again, and add the MSDN Libary on.

Comment: This is Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5

Installed Edition: VB Express

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91908-152-0000043-60750
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

That I downloaded about July 2008

Comment: thanks .... I think I need to download the whole thing .. I thought MSDN lib was for articles, not basic reference.

Comment: Then its: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=6FF3BC60-32C8-4C22-8591-A20BF8DFF1A2&displaylang=en

But again there is some documentation with the application, are you use that you did not tick MSDN Documentation off in the install process?

Comment: thanks ... but as Dexter points out, my God! 2 gigs!! I may be forced to though, as his other suggestion for online help doesn't work

Comment: I don't know if I mussed ticking the documentation from the install process. I suppose there's no "lighter" way to get it retrospectively?

Answer (score 0):

run microsoft visual studio 2008 documentation with 'run as administrator' option. visual studio should be closed, then check all the settings. close and then try within visual studio, it should work now